# JVM not recognized by the Oracle Solaris Studio x86 installer

Tags: java, jvm, solaris

I am trying to run the Oracle Solaris Studio for Linux x86 installer and the same issue occurs on both OS X and Ubuntu. After typing

```
sudo ./solarisstudio.sh --non-interactive --libraries-only
```

in the Terminal, what is printed on the screen is:

```
Configuring the installer...
Searching for JVM on the system...
Java installation was not found on this computer
Java 1.5.0_03 or later is required for installing Oracle Solaris Studio. Make sure that Java is properly installed and run installer again.
You can specify valid Java location using --javahome installer argument.

To download Java installation bundle (JDK or JRE), visit http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html
```

After installing JDK and setting up environment variables, the same issue continues.

Webpages I followed to set-up environment variables:

```
https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-set-java_home-path-variable/
https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-set-java_home-environment-variable-on-mac-os-x/
```

Comment: Are the JAVA_HOME and JDK_HOME environment variables set?

Comment: It was set but the same issue continues. In OS X I used export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home). And echo $JAVA_HOME and which java are working.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the java home in your path
or otherwise use the option provided

`sudo ./solarisstudio.sh --non-interactive --libraries-only --javahome <our java location>`